# Calculate discount using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML structure like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>

   <book id="bk101">
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <sale-price>4.90</sale-price>
   </book>

   <book id="bk102">
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <sale-price>4.90</sale-price>
   </book>

</catalog>
```

I want to select nodes where the sale price is discounted more than 30% from the regular price. How can I do that using XPath?

Comment: I think xquery may be more suited, but am not familiar to that level in either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//book[(price - sale-price) div price > 0.3]
```

Above xpath return all `<book>` nodes having sale-price discounted more than 30% from the regular price.

Output :

```
<book id="bk101">
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <sale-price>4.90</sale-price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is that you want books where the `sale-price` is less than 70% of the `price`.

In Xpath:

`sale-price div price < 0.7`

Make this a condition for the book element nodes

`/catalog/book[sale-price div price < 0.7]`

PHP Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>

   <book id="bk101">
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <sale-price>4.90</sale-price>
   </book>

   <book id="bk102">
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <sale-price>4.90</sale-price>
   </book>

</catalog>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$expression = '/catalog/book[
  sale-price div price < 0.7
]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  echo $dom->saveXml($node);
}
```

Output:

```
<book id="bk101">
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <sale-price>4.90</sale-price>
</book>
```